# Swift 5 - Intercept all selectors

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

Suppose I have these 3 selectors:

```swift
extension Selector {
    static let func1 = #selector(GameViewController.func1(_:))
    static let func2 = #selector(GameViewController.func2(_:))
    static let func3 = #selector(GameViewController.func3(_:))
}
```

But I want to add a flag check to each of their target functions like so:

```swift
class GameViewController {
    var animInProgress = false

    @objc func func1(_ payload: Notification) {
        guard let userInfo = payload.userInfo,
        !animInProgress else { return }
    }

    @objc func func2(_ payload: Notification) {
        guard let userInfo = payload.userInfo,
        !animInProgress else { return }
    }

    @objc func func3(_ payload: Notification) {
        guard let userInfo = payload.userInfo,
        !animInProgress else { return }
    }
}
```

That would get tedious pretty quickly.  Is there a way that I could write an interceptor like this?

```swift
class GameViewController {
    var animInProgress = false

    @objc func interceptor(_ payload: Notification, funcName: funcName) {
        if animInProgress { return }
        // Call function here with payload
    }
}
```

And would the Selectors look like this?

```swift
extension Selector {
    static let func1 = #selector(GameViewController.interceptor(_:,["func", "func1"]))
    static let func2 = #selector(GameViewController.interceptor(_:,["func", "func2"]))
    static let func3 = #selector(GameViewController.interceptor(_:,["func", "func3"]))
}
```

Comment: This would be certainly possible by going into Objective-C runtime. However, if you need such things, in 99% of cases it means you should change your architecture. Why don't you use a single notification handler instead? Also "selector" literally means "function name". You cannot have a single selector than somehow contains multiple function names.

Comment: Target/action is quite restrictive. For example you can't specify custom parameters.

Comment: Well that's not good.  Sulthan, that may be good idea.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have an AB problem here?

Comment: Sulthan - actually, I already do have a single function where all UI selector calls go.  But it's, of course, outside of the view controller.  That still leaves me with the problem of calling a function IN the view controller to check a flag IN the view controller.

Comment: Paulw11 - whats an AB problem?

Comment: Sorry, I should have said [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem?wprov=sfti1)

Comment: Paulw11 - whats an XY problem?